# How do I filter all points within an OSM shape?

Tags: r, gis, openstreetmap

I'm trying to find all stations inside Manhattan from the CitiBikes dataset. I can get the shape of Manhattan from OpenStreetMap by

```
q <- opq(bbox="Manhattan")
q <- add_osm_feature(q, key="name", value="Manhattan")
q <- add_osm_feature(q, key="boundary", value="administrative")
administrative <- osmdata_sf (q)
manhattan = administrative$osm_multipolygons[1]
plot(manhattan, main="Manhattan borough")
```

and I can convert the data to Simple Geometry points by

```
cbike <- read.csv(file="201903-citibike-tripdata.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, 
                  sep=",", na.strings=c("NA","NaN", "NULL"))
cbike$start.sf <- cbike %>%
  select(lat=start.station.latitude, lon=start.station.longitude) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords=c("lon", "lat"), crs=st_crs(manhattan))
```

but I cannot get which points lie inside `manhattan`. I assume that I want to use `st_intersection` or `st_intersects` in order to get a boolean vector, but I'm a bit lost at how that works: Any predicate comes up as empty.

```
> inside = cbike$start.sf[1,1]
> inside
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -74.00945 ymin: 40.71107 xmax: -74.00945 ymax: 40.71107
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
                    geometry
1 POINT (-74.00945 40.71107)
```

This is a point on Fulton Street, clearly inside Manhattan. However, `st_intersects(inside, manhattan)` and `st_within(inside, manhattan)` are both empty. (`st_intersects(inside, inside)` and `st_intersects(manhattan, manhattan)` are both `TRUE`, so I assume it's not that points or multipolygons cannot be intersected in general)

(This is with the `osmdata`, `sf`, and `dplyr` packages.)

Comment: Which libraries are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the validity of the Manhattan geometry? Check out https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html#corrup-or-invalid-geometries! You don't seem to be using the `lwgeom` libary. Installing it (from sources, likely), loading, and then running `st_make_valid` on `manhattan` gives a valid geometry that has non-empty intersection with points in Manhattan:

```
manhattan <- st_make_valid(manhattan)

cbike$start.sf <- cbike %>%
  select(lat=start.station.latitude, lon=start.station.longitude) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords=c("lon", "lat"), crs=st_crs(manhattan))

cbike$starts.inside.manhattan <- st_intersects(cbike$start.sf, manhattan, sparse=FALSE)[,1]
```

(the return value of `st_intersects` is the n×1 matrix of pairwise intersections, of which only the first column is required)

```
> cbike$starts.inside.manhattan
   [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
  [21]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Only one question. Why must be the `sf` way? Why not convert to `sp` objects.'

Comment: No particular reason. I'm figuring this out as I go. I'm happy to be shown a better way to do it using `sp`.

Comment: `sf` is generally faster and will be better supported in future. Stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select only Manhattan start stations, it can be done just from coords of bbox:

```
xmin <- as.numeric(sub("(.*),.*,.*,.*", "\\1", administrative[[1]]))
xmax <- as.numeric(sub(".*,.*,(.*),.*", "\\1", administrative[[1]]))
ymin <- as.numeric(sub(".*,.*,.*,(.*)", "\\1", administrative[[1]]))
ymax <- as.numeric(sub(".*,(.*),.*,.*", "\\1", administrative[[1]]))

cbike$start_sf <- cbike %>%
  select(lat=`Start Station Latitude`, lon=`Start Station Longitude`) %>% 
subset(., (lat>=xmin & lat<=xmax & lon<=ymin & lon>=ymax)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords=c("lon", "lat"), crs=st_crs(manhattan))
```

Comment: But the bounding box is bigger than Manhattan only, and therefore would probably include stations outside the borough?